# Function (Stored Procedure) on inserted document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document with a numeric field that's populate on new inserted document.
That value need retrieved for date and field max value.

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: Hi, @Krishna. In csharp and sql server I could to use trigger type on insert for to update a field that depend to other fields.
How to can I to do it with mongodb?

Regards

Comment: There are no triggers in mongodb.

Comment: There can be multiple ways to achieve this. but we need specifics before suggesting any solution. Thats why explain more of your question.

Comment: Hi @Krishna. I need get the max value of a numeric field for specific date, add 1 to retrieved value and update that field for new document.

Answer (score 0):

This the the SQL code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnProgressivoCliente] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    --<@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Data_Type_For_Param1, , int>
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @progressivo int

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    set @progressivo=(select ISNULL(max(c.progressivo),0)+1
                        from tbClienti c
                        where CONVERT(date,c.Data)=CONVERT(date,getdate())
                     )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @progressivo

END
```

Regards

Comment: HI @Krishna.
Can you tell me a way reaching the target on mongodb

Comment: try stored javascript on mongodb server and invoking it after insert.

Comment: While in sql server can I to call that function in inserted trigger, how to do it in mongodb?

Comment: use `db.eval()`

Comment: It is deprecated and I would must to create a level server function, that I would lost on first update server